# How can I iterate over dynamicall created parameters?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

My code dynamically creates forms with names like this:

```
<div ng-click="wos.wordWordFormRowClicked(wf, $index)"
     ng-form="wos.wordFormNgForm_{{$index}}"
     ng-repeat="wf in wos.word.wordForms">
```

wos is the name of the service.

What I would like to do is to iterate over these and check their $pristine. I think I can do it something like this:

```
    angular.forEach(self.word.wordForms, function (wf, key) {
        // ?
    });
```

What I would like to know is how inside the forEach can I get a reference to the wos service parameter that will be dynamically created?

These parameters would be something like this:

```
    wos.wordFormNgForm_1.$pristine
    wos.wordFormNgForm_2.$pristine
    wos.wordFormNgForm_3.$pristine
```

Comment: I think you could just use wos.wordFormNgForm_1.['$pristine']

Comment: @Katana24 - but how could I put that inside my forEach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's "Controller as" syntax can help us to bind the FormController with Controller of current view.

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='default as wos'>
      <div ng-click="wos.wordWordFormRowClickd(wf, $index)"
           ng-form="wos.wordFormNgForm_{{$index}}"
           ng-repeat="wf in wos.wordForms">  
      </div>
</div>
```

Also, we can use array syntax to access Object's properties.

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('default', function() {  
    this.wordForms = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
    this.checkForm = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.wordForms.length; i ++) {
            console.log(this["wordFormNgForm_" + i].$pristine);
    }
 }
})
```

Please refer a working version in my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DoTH/mnqfgsb2/2/)